# Extend C++ application (executable) with dynamically linked library code?

Tags: c++

I **do not want to provide client with source code to an application (executable)** but do want to allow the client to extend application functionality by modifying source written in a dynamically linked library.

The executable has a function called **void handleGetResource(request, response)** to handle incoming http requests.

**handleGetResource** is where the client's business logic resides.  This is the C++ user code specific to the client.

*I would like to compile this user code into a dynamic library so that I can provide the client only with the source code related to their business logic.  This way, they can modify and rebuild this business logic without having access to my executable's source code.*

Can someone provide me with some advice on how to best handle this?  Both the app and the dynamic libraries would be written in C++.  Note: the executable is cross compiled to run on Win and Linux.

Thank you

Comment: What operating system?  My answer for Windows will be different from Unix/Mac.

Comment: At the bottom of my message, I had indicated both Windows and Linux.  My executable is written in C++ and the exact same code builds under Windows and Linux.

Comment: Shared library mechanisms are OS specific, so you'd need at least a bit of platform-dependent code. Or use a third-party framework that abstracts it for you. You are probably already using some framework, if you are able to write an HTTP server that works under Windows and Linux without having anything OS-specific in your code (this means the OS-specific parts are in someone else's code you use).

Comment: Yes Igor, Boost Asio.  I was thinking of setting up some define directives for the application specific code when creating the dynamic libraries.  If you have any other suggestions, comments, pros/cons I would really appreciate hearing about.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are describing is a plugin model where users or customers can provide their own compiled extensions to "handle" functionality on behalf of an application.

On Windows, you specify that customers build a DLL and export a function that matches your expected function signature. On Linux, you ask them to build a shared library (.so) - which is nearly the same thing as a DLL.

In your application, you will invoke [LoadLibrary](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/libloaderapi/nf-libloaderapi-loadlibrarya?msclkid=d621a9d3ae1a11ecbbbb1cb1f2502f93) and [GetProcAddress](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/libloaderapi/nf-libloaderapi-getprocaddress) to load the customer's DLL from file and to get a function pointer to his implementation of handleGetResource:

```
 typedef void (__stdcall *HANDLE_GET_RESOURCE)(Request* request, Response* response);
 HMODULE hMod = LoadLibrary("C:\\Path\\To\\Customers\\Dll\\TheirHandler.dll");
 HANDLE_GET_REQUEST handler = (HANDLE_GET_RESOURCE)GetProcAdderss(hMod, "handleGetResource");
```

Then to invoke:

```
 handler(&request, &response);
```

Then your customer can build a DLL with a definition like the following:

```
extern "C"  __declspec(dllexport) void __stdcall handleGetResource(Request* req, Response* res)
{
   // their code goes here
}
```

You can do the same thing on Linux with [dlopen and dlsym](https://linux.die.net/man/3/dlopen) in place of LoadLibrary and GetProcAddress.

For Windows, I would also be explicitly in having these typedefs and function defintions be explict with regards to [__cdecl](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/cdecl?view=msvc-170) or [__stdcall](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/stdcall?view=msvc-170).

As to how the customer registers the full path to their compiled binary - that's a mechanism that you can decide for yourself. (e.g. command line, registry, expected file name in current directory, etc...)

Comment: Thank you for your 'plugin model' answer.  I've never done this before and I appreciate your comment.  Really surprised to get so many down votes by others.  Yes, I've created test dlls in the past but I guess that I'm worried that the 'plugin model' will bring some unwanted consequences, e.g. complications for me or the client.

Comment: The only minor concern is a potential security exploit. Use explicit registrations to a full path of the DLL to load and don't auto-load anything that isn't registered.

Comment: Selbie, one last question regarding the 'plugin model'.  The main server executable has a great many functions that user code would need, for example get/set cookies, url/file parsing, session/cache handling, etc.  Can I simply provide existing header files to the functions or do they need to be modified in some way so that the user can access them from their code?  Thanks again.

Comment: Multiple options.  First option.  Expose these helper functions as a C++ pure virtual class to `handleGetResource`.  Ala `void handleGetResource(Request* req, Response* res, IHelperFunctions *pHelperFunction)`.  Where IHelperFunctions is a C++ interface of all pure virtual methods.  This would be my preferred choice.

Comment: Options 2. Move all these utility functions into its own DLL that both your EXE and the customer's plugin can access within the same process. This assumes all the EXEs and DLLs install out of the same directory.  You give the customer "helper.lib" (and helper.h which has the function declaration), which is the stub library for "helper.dll".  Has the advantage of only being loaded into memory once.

Comment: Option 3. Expose all the helper functions as a static lib. Give the customer who implements the plugin, the .lib file and .h file.

Comment: I just realized a problem problem with #1. And that is the customer doesn't an easy way to develop his code independently of running within your EXE.  That will be cumbersome for initial development and he won't have an easy time developing his own EXE to test his DLL.  So option #3 is actually the best on the table - but assumes these functions don't share state with the exe.